# Should I unsubscribe from Observable in jest/jasmine tests?

Tags: rxjs, jasmine, jestjs

When I check if my observables are emitting what I need my unit tests. Should I unsubscribe inside my test?

I have always seen stuff like this:

```
it('my test should return 10', fakeAsync(() => {
  let valueObtained;
  sut.myObservable$.subscribe(newValue => {
    valueObtained = newValue;
  });

  sut.act();
  tick();
  expect(valueObtained).toBe(10)
});
```

should I use there after the `expect` an `.unsubscribe` ?

Comment: Does it cause you any problems? If you don't unsubscribe, you may run into memory leak problems, however I doubt this would be a problem with tests since they run and close the browser instance.

Comment: No that I found. But since jest does not use a browser instance and the project where I work has more than 1000 suites I am now curious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to unsubscribe from subscriptions in my unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312433/do-i-need-to-unsubscribe-from-subscriptions-in-my-unit-tests)

Comment: @ХристиянХристов if the same applies to jest instead of Karma then yes, the question is the same.